# how to fetch the value of radio button in radio button to another page using html and php

Tags: php, html

I have a form where members details are entered,

If i click submit it takes all values and stores in db. But if i click edit it is retrieving all values except radio button value.

So, how to fetch the radio button value while editing the page?

**This is my code where i try to fetch the value of radio button it fetches value but it is not fetching the value in radio button**

```
<td>Gender</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="<?php echo $gender; ?>" />Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="<?php echo $gender; ?>" >Female
    </td>
```

Comment: can you give some more insight into what code currently have?

Answer (score 0):

When you send data through PHP and HTML you just get it like this :
`$var = $_GET['field']; //if you used GET method`
But it works with everything, not only text. The fact is just you have to name your radiobutons and get their values :
`<input type="radio" name="radio1" /><input type="radio" name="radio2" />` and after in PHP you have to know which one was checked, basically (I'm not sure but...) it will work like that :
`if ($_GET['radio1'] == 'on' /*on is valable for checkboxes*/) { /* your stuff here */ }`

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, I think what you are doing incorrectly is you need to name all of your radio buttons the same with seperate values.

i.e.

```
<input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="Easy">
<input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="Medium">
<input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="Hard">
```

Now $_POST['difficulty'] should grab the data of the radio.

Comment: ya i used it.... but only radio button value is not working other than it all values are coming...